# Можно ли методом strip (или каким-либо другим методом str) удалить из начала и конца определённое количество элементов?

Tags: python

пример.

```
из строки '"""asd"""'
нужно получить '""asd""' 
strip('"', 1)
```

Comment: Это можно сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Специального такого метода нет. Если не обобщать на любое количество символов, а удалять по одному, то можно так (символы удаляются только если они есть в начале или в конце строки):

```
def strip_once(s, chars=' '):
    if s and s[0] in chars:
        s = s[1:]
    if s and s[-1] in chars:
        s = s[:-1]
    return s
```

Эту функцию писал довольно давно: [po.py](https://github.com/dfint/df-gettext-toolkit/blob/master/df_gettext_toolkit/po.py#L8)

Если нужно именно с указанием конкретного n, то можно через регулярные выражения:

```
import re

def strip_n(s, chars, n=1):
    # Формируем регулярное выражение вида r"^[abc]{,n}(.*?)[abc]{,n}$"
    regex = r"^[{chars}]{{,{n}}}(.*?)[{chars}]{{,{n}}}$".format(chars=chars, n=n)
    return re.search(regex, s).group(1)

print(strip_n('"""asd"""', '"', 2))
print(strip_n('"""asd"', '"', 2))
print(strip_n('asd', '"', 2))
```

Вывод:

```
"asd"
"asd
asd
```

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать элементарно через стандартный доступ по [индексу](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)  :

```py
st = 'hhhtttkkk'
st2 = st[1:-1]
```

Comment: Даже с середины по известному индексу
`st2 = st[0:3] + st[7:3]`